# Development lifecycle for fast starting pods (with dependency on slow starting pods)

Tags: google-cloud-code

I have an app with several pods. The foundational pod takes about 2 minutes to start fully but I basically never need to change it. I'm working on other pods and they start in few seconds if the foundational pod is already running. I'm trying to optimize my development lifecycle when I change the code in fast-starting pod and debugging it.

The "Run on Kubernetes" would be great as it watched the changes and re-deploys that fast-starting pod only. However, I can't debug it.

"Debug on Kubernetes" is what I would like to use but it doesn't watch the changes and re-deploy automatically and stopping and starting the whole app (all pods) is pain because it takes 2-3 minutes (due to slow starting but never changing pods).

I was thinking of have "Run on Kubernetes" and then use Attach to debug individual pods but it would require pre-configuring the pods/containers for debug in Dockerfile. I assume if I do that, I could detach debugger and let it re-deploy watching changes and re-attach again.

I was playing with multiple skaffold yaml files - one that includes foundation only (slow starting pod) and another one just for fast-starting pod where I need to do changes but then I have to disable clean up so it's manual pod stopping for me. Also, it seems to keep stopping/starting minikube when I stop/start "Debug on Kubernetes".

I wish I could just use "Debug on Kubernetes" that watches changes and re-deploys. But watch is not supported for Debug runs.

Am I missing anything? Any good ideas?

Comment: Developer on Cloud Code here: you're correct that Cloud Code doesn't support watch mode when debugging at the moment. I recommend filing a feature request on GitHub with this use-case. I assume you are using VS Code? 

http://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-code-vscode

Comment: Also, splitting up into multiple skaffold files is a good workaround (or simply deploying your long running "foundational" pod and keeping it running on the cluster, limiting the skaffold config to the artifacts under development). Though it sounds like you are running on minikube, and CC is stopping the cluster at the end of the debug session forcing you to redeploy your foundational pod each time - is this correct?

Comment: I did open a feature request. Yes.

Comment: I’ve been using vscode to start with and it seems like it does stop minikube at the end. Also it seems there is a bug with cleanup - no matter what scaffold file I use - on clean up is still trying to find scaffold.yaml. I may confirm and open a bug.

Comment: I’m also trying now to use Google Cloud Shell and minikube there doesn’t pause. Also deploying and building from there is much faster for me for both minikube and GKE. Also, minikube doesn’t stop there automatically (maybe my local setup is screwed on vscode - I also trying docker-desktop context instead of minikube but it doesn’t seem to be stable). So far, my best experience is to deploy my dev stuff on GKE. I’ve switched to cloud Shell editor for now and I like it (seems like vscode based).

Answer (score 0):

@Alex - thanks for filing the [issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-code-vscode/issues/400). Will followup further discussion on it. Glad to hear you like using cloud shell we provide same experience there that is available in VSCode. Regarding minikube stop it is intended behavior for local debugging but we can discuss more on the ticket. Sorry it doesn't let me comment inline for now.